# Deploy packages as zip files through Octopus Deploy?

Tags: octopus-deploy

I am using TeamCity to compile my projects, then deploying them through Octopus Deploy. Both windows. It just works! Nice.

Now, I want to release zip files for download, i.e. they shouldn't be deployed to my environments as such.

Since .nupkg as actually .zip files in disguise, I should think this is achievable? But how?

On my target web server, I've got a folder for downloading the zip files, so I just need help renaming and copying the package?

Comment: What have you tried doing in order to accomplish this?  And what issue are you getting?

Comment: Out-of-the-box, OD deploys the contents of nupkg to Applications/app/version. I want to keep it as zip as users need to download and install on their machine outside my domain. I'm asking how to intercept and copy the nupkg file, preferably keeping verion info.

Comment: This is what I was looking for rather than cooking it up myself. Problem solved! https://octopus.com/docs/deployment-process/deploying-packages/transfer-package

Comment: Sorry I added my post after seeing that you resolved it already :facepalm: . Gonna leave it there in case it helps other ppl that run into this thread :)

Comment: No harm done, Dalmiro - thanks for helping out! I marked your answer as The Answer as indeed it is :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the Transfer Package feature of OD

https://octopus.com/docs/deployment-process/deploying-packages/transfer-package